# UNIX vi parameters

Tags: unix, editor, vi

A co-worker passed me a snippet of his ".bashrc" file, which includes these 2 lines:

```
alias vi='vi -b -i NONE'
alias view='vi -b -i NONE -R'
```

I have searched for "UNIX vi parameters", "UNIX vi command line", and "vi arguments" but have not been successful.

What effect do the parameters -b, -i, -R, and NONE have on executing vi?  Can anyone direct me to an online resource discussing these?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `man vi` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your coworker has set up some handy shortcuts for editing (`vi`) and reading (`view`) files.

Check `man vi` for the manual. https://linux.die.net/man/1/vi mirrors this info:

> `-b`
> Binary mode. A few options will be set that makes it possible to edit a binary or executable file.
>
> `-i {viminfo}`
> When using the viminfo file is enabled, this option sets the filename to use, instead of the default "~/.viminfo". This can also be used to skip the use of the .viminfo file, by giving the name "NONE".
>
> `-R`
> Read-only mode. The 'readonly' option will be set. You can still edit the buffer, but will be prevented from accidently overwriting a file. If you do want to overwrite a file, add an exclamation mark to the Ex command, as in ":w!". The -R option also implies the -n option (see below). The 'readonly' option can be reset with ":set noro". See ":help 'readonly'".

So: `alias vi='vi -b -i NONE'` will open vi, ready to edit binary files, and with no viminfo file. `alias view='vi -b -i NONE -R'` will do the same, but in read-only mode.